# Parse Value and Append Parsed Value to end of URL using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need a solution to parse the value in the URL split between `%2526_ga%253d` and `&wct` then append `&_ga=` + `the parsed value` to the end of the same URL.

This is my URL, which is always different but `%2526_ga%253d` and `&wct` is always the same.
http://www.example.com/wa=wsignin1.0%2526_ga%253d1.193373933.1506621463.1391436765&wct=2014-04-25T19

The end result would be:
http://www.example.com/wa=wsignin1.0%2526_ga%253d1.193373933.1506621463.1391436765&wct=2014-04-25T19`&_ga=1.193373933.1506621463.1391436765`

I completed my solution and this works:

```
var gacookie = window.location.search.match('_ga%253d(.+)&wct=');
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf('_ga') > -1) {
        url += '&_ga=' + gacookie[1]
        parent.location.hash = url
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', gacookie[1]); 
        if(hash != '') {
        location.hash = '&_ga=' + gacookie[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What solutions have you looked at so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the finished result. Thank you @Mattias for helping me with the match.

```
var gacookie = window.location.search.match('_ga%253d(.+)&wct=');
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf('_ga') > -1) {
        url += '&_ga=' + gacookie[1]
        parent.location.hash = url
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', gacookie[1]); 
        if(hash != '') {
        location.hash = '&_ga=' + gacookie[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a RegEx:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/wa=wsignin1.0%2526_ga%253d1.193373933.1506621463.1391436765&wct=2014-04-25T19';
var value = url.match('_ga%(.+)&wct=');
url = url + "&_ga=" + value[1];
```

You should probably add some validation logic too...

Comment: Thank you. This helped me with the match. I updated my script with a solution, but I don't know how to do it without the page refresh.